# Mac AppStore badge does not reset after installing update

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I am experiencing a strange problem: after I installed a bunch of updates, the Mac AppStore badge was not reset. When I go to "Updates", I get the message "no updates available".
I tried to

- delete the AppStore cookie
- rebuild the Spotlight index (found a recommendation to do so somewhere)
- logged out and in the AppStore
- delete some of the updated Apps and re-installed them

without any effect. Today, I got an update for another application; the update count was incremented and was not reset again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reboot did the trick. Badge is reset.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than rebooting, you can just type `killall Dock` from your terminal application. It will reset the dock and clear the badges.

Comment: That trick didn't work for me. The badge was removed for a few moments, but popped up again.

Comment: Did the new alerts pop up because you had valid messages? The killall Dock is something Apple actually recommends on their support site.

Comment: No, there weren't any updates at that time. After one update was available the problem is now resolved for me.